# Wordpress: How to copy your productive environment to create a test-environment?

Tags: wordpress, testing, environment, staging

What are the steps, which are needed to create a copy of a productive wordpress environment for testing purposes, respectively to create a staging environment?

Comment: Reference: [Codex: Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was discussed extensively on [WordPress.Stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119/easily-move-a-wordpress-install-from-development-to-production/182#182) [@Mike Schinkel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102699/mikeschinkel) is developing a migration plugin that handles the database and url issues.  The download link is in the above referenced answer.

Comment: Sorry, did not know that there exists a wordpress-specific stackexchange. It would be great if stackoverflow would indicate that there is such a stackexchange, when a question with the word "wordpress" in the title or in a tag is asked.

Comment: Might be something to bring up on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder for the test-environment
2. Password-protect this folder (e.g. with htaccess/htpasswd), so that no one (user, search-engine) accesses this test-environment by accident
3. Copy content of the folder in which wordpress is installed into the test-folder
4. Copy the database
5. Change the following in the wp-config.php:

   1. Database-Connection settings
   2. change `define('WP_SITEURL', 'myUrlToTestInstallation');`
6. Login into the Wordpress-Backend of the test-environment and go to

   1. Options -> General and change "Blog-Address (URL)"
   2. Options -> Media and change "Upload path"

You're finished. Now you should have a staging environment set up.